# Finding strictly function that satisfies this limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to find a strictly increasing function $\varphi: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \lim_{y \to x} \frac{2x - a - b}{\varphi(y) - \varphi(x)} = 0 $ and $ \lim_{y \to x} \frac{a + b -2y}{\varphi(y) - \varphi(x)} = 0 $

**Background:**

Let $f,F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ then f is an MC-derivative (monotonically controlled derivative) of F if $\exists \varphi : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ strictly increasing s.t $ \lim_{y \to x} \frac{F(y) - F(x) -f(x)(y-x)}{\varphi(y) - \varphi(x)} = 0 $ with $x,y \in [a,b]$.

I encountered the problem above when attempting to show this holds for step functions, in particular: $f(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{l l}
    -1 & \quad \text{$x \in [a, \frac{a+b}{2})$}\\
    1 & \quad \text{$x \in [\frac{a+b}{2},b]$}
  \end{array} \right. $

$F(x) = \left\{  \begin{array}{l l}
    a-x & \quad \text{$x \in [a, \frac{a+b}{2})$}\\
    x-b & \quad \text{$x \in [\frac{a+b}{2},b]$}
  \end{array} \right. $

Thanks.